# How to show/hide column values on specific rows in an Oracle APEX report?

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex

I have an Interactive Report with the following sample column/data:

```
    ID   COMPANY    NAME          S     P     C     R     W
    ---- ---------- ------------- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
    1    ABC        HARRY         S           C     R     W
    2    QAZ        SAM                 P     C     R     W
```

Basically, I need a means of being able to show/hide individual column elements on a per row/column basis and not the whole column itself.

Using the above IR, each of the column values beneath the column headings S | P | C | R | W are actually links.

So when the user for instance clicks the "S" link against ID. 1 record, I need a means of hiding column element "R" and only showing column elements "C" and "W". In addition to this, the original "S" (for Start), that was clicked will turn on the "P" (Paused) link, alongside it and the "S" link will be switched off (updated in the backend against ID. 1 record.

So for record ID. 1, after clicking on "S", the record should now look as follows, always keeping the column headings intact for all rows.

I need this to also appear (as below), when the page is re-queried.

```
    ID   COMPANY    NAME          S     P     C     R     W
    ---- ---------- ------------- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
    1    ABC        HARRY               P     C           W
```

The same type of scenario would be applicable to ID. 2 record - if the user clicks on "P", then I need to hide column elements "R" and "W" for ID. 2 record only. At the same time, the "P" link will be switched off and once again, the "S" link will appear/be switched on. So ID 2 record when clicked/re-queried will now appear as follows:

```
    ID   COMPANY    NAME          S     P     C     R     W
    ---- ---------- ------------- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
    2    QAZ        SAM           S           C
```

Obviously I will need a jQuery/Dynamic Action click function but unsure how to target particular cells for a particular row that I just clicked on.

Comment: You'll need to explain a bit more about the elements: for instance, when I click a P-link and elements are hidden, what will this record look like when requeried? Will the P-link be there again, together with the other links? How can we distinguish between used and non-used links?

Comment: Hi Tom, hopefully my updates above assist with your queries - thanks.

Comment: So, wouldn't it be just as interesting to fire an ajax call when you click S or P, and then refresh the report? By doing so you'll avoid having to hide/remove elements or even inject them. eg when P isn't present and R and W neither, you'll have to create the html again in javascript. A refresh would save a lot of work.

Comment: Sounds good Tom - will try this and report back.

Comment: Tom, did what you suggested and also realised that there was another column within the report that I could use to trigger the elements on and off. All good now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this problem with the help of Tom as well as using another column within the table, that the report was based off, to trigger required elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a solution in Applications (if somebody still interested):

You can editing the columns of the riport one-by-one, clicking on the rendering, your region/columns folder. In Identification there is a type, where you can choose hidden.